# Text aligns oddly.

Tags: html, css

In the following image, I've outlined 3 things in red, the first is the the title of a box with the words `'Final Fantasy IV'`, the second box is `'Sonic Chronicles: The Dark Brotherhood`, and the third is the css styling of the title as displayed by Chrome.

My issue is that in the first box, labeled `'Final Fantasy IV'`, you can see it looks ok, and there's no overlapping, in the second box however, you can see some font overlapping.  What's some CSS magic I can do to fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why is that div absolutely positioned?

Comment: Because I needed something of positioning.  Is this somehow an issue?

Comment: Just that generally, if you need elements to align to other elements, it's better to position them normally and use floats to create "sidebars". Absolute positioning is something I'd use to make elements hover over other elements (like a popup dialog), not to place elements in the regular flow of content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's some CSS magic I can do to fix this?

CSS Magic:

```
position: relative;
```

CSS `position` documentation:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

Comment: I've got some problems with this.  Even if I set `display:block`, the text no longer wraps.  Do I need set the width of the div?

Comment: Put it in a container div and set the width to something small enough to wrap.

Comment: Ok, I did.  Thanks!  

Is there any reason this might have been happening with Absolute? 

Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Absolute and fixed positioning don't affect the flow of other elements on the page because that behaviour is sometimes needed.

Comment: Right, but I don't understand the cramping caused by absolute, but NOT relative.  Still need more training I suppose.

Comment: @Adola I added a link to documentation in the answer, so you can read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the image above the text, i.e. `resultIMG` is taking time to d/l, and that it is not downloaded when the browser is making it's calculations. You sometimes see this sort of thing when using JS to set equal height columns, where one of htem contains a large image. Worth looking into. Try setting a height on resultIMG, if you can